# Convert der certificate to p12

Tags: air, adobe, der, p12

I am trying to upload my adobe air app to Google Play. I have opted in for Google Play App Signing and cannot opt out now. They provide me with .der certificate which I wish to convert to p12 in order to use it in my adobe AIR app. I know this can be done through openSSL but I did not get any perfect tutorial to do so. Can anyone point me to the right steps to make this conversion?

Comment: do you have a `.key` file?

Comment: Have you solved it? I also wonder how the upload cert is supposed to be used:/

Answer (score 0):

DER file is  X.509 certificate. So it includes your certificate.
You can try below steps to convert .DER file into p12 file. These steps worked for me.

**Option 1:**

1. If you are using MAC, you can drag and drop .DER file into Keychain   Access.
2. After it is imported to Keychain.
3. Export that certificate into p12 file by selecting that certificate from Keychain. Right click on certificate, You will get option to export. 
   If you don't get p12 option, export it into .cer  and convert it into p12 using below command

openssl pkcs12 -info -in keyStore.p12

**Option 2:**
 Use below commands to convert DER into P12. I already tried and tested them.

1. Get private key or generate private key if you don’t have.
2. You can generate private key using below command. If private key is not generate for DER format, then convert your DER file into PEM file using openssl command(openssl x509 -inform der -in certificatename.der -out certificatename.pem). 
   openssl rsa -in certificate.der -out privatekey.key -outform DER
3. Export DER into p12
   openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.p12 -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.der. -certfile certificate.der

For More details on ssl commands you can also look at them on below link https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO26449.html

Hope that helps

Comment: The problem is, that the upload_cert.der contains only public key, so it is not possible to export it as p12